# Injecting $resource throwing exception - Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

Iam new to angularJS. Trying to Understand more on $resource and $http methods. whatever I implemented to communicate with the server using $resource is throwing exception at the initial point on injection.
($http all the actions are working fine)

Code shown below:

```
 'use strict';

    angular.module('angularApp').constant("baseUrl", "http://localhost:3000/")
        .factory('AccountFactory', ['$resource','baseUrl', function ($resource, baseUrl) {

            var accountObj = {};

            var accounts = $resource(baseUrl + "getAllAccounts",
                {
                    userId: '@id'
                }
            );

            accountObj.getAllAccounts = function () {
                accounts.get(function (req) {
                    console.log("success");
                }, function (req) {
                    console.log("failure");
                });
            }

            return accountObj;
        }]);
```

[see the browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QALP4.jpg)

Please correct me if iam doing anything wrong in the above implementation.

Comment: are you injecting ngResource in your module?

Answer (score 0):

you need to inject first ngResource module

```
 angular.module('angularApp',[ngResource]).constant
```